# How to update record using angular post?

Tags: channel-entries, update, js

I am trying to update record by angular post, below is code:

```
 $.post(url, data, function (result) {
                var error = false;
                if (result.success == 1 && (result.entry_id) != false) {
                    //alert('Saved Successfully!!')
                } else {
                    error = true;
                }
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    if (error) {
                        $scope.error = true;
                        $scope.ErrorMessage = 'Internal server error occured.';
                    } else {
                        $scope.success = true;
                        window.location.href = "#/trVenueDetail/" + result.entry_id
                    }
                });

            });
```

But it's always made the new entry. Page URL is some thing like below:

http://example.com/new#/trAddVenue/47452

47452 is entry_id, I have tried to set it in hidden field:

The entry_id hidden field is automatically created by form tag.

```
  {exp:channel:form channel="venues" include_jquery="no" json="yes"
id="addVenu" name="addVenu" }

     -- Controls Html Is Here---

  {/exp:channel:form}
```

The Same code is working in case of add new record, but how to update existing.

And yes I am able to populate the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the answer by myself, in case of update we have to set the require_entry="yes" and need to pass the entry_id.

```
 {exp:channel:form channel="venues" entry_id="{segment_3}" require_entry="yes" include_jquery="no" json="yes" id="addVenu" name="addVenu" }

       -- Controls Html Is Here---

  {/exp:channel:form}
```

It will force to update rather then the new entry.

I hope this will help someone else.